# How Eigen operators are interpreted as MKL functions internally?

Tags: c++, memory, eigen, eigen3, intel-mkl

Eigen is a very convenient library that can express the mathematic formula in a concise and human-intuitive way. I know that Eigen has lazy evaluation concepts that can represent a chain of operations in expression classes and efficiently evaluate it when necessary. I also know that Eigen can be used with MKL. However, I'm curious about what kind of expressions can be transferred into MKL cblas calls. Under what condition, they are not transferable? Are there any general rules that can help me figure out what is transferable?

Typically, I'm curious about the following cases:

```
MatrixXd A, B, C;
VectorXd a, b, c;
double w1, w2, w3;

b += w1 * A * a;  // can be done through dgemv
b += w1 * A.transpose() * a;  // can be done through dgemv
C += w2 * A * B;  // can be done through dgemm
C += w2 * A.transpose() * B;  // can be done through dgemm
C += w2 * A. topRows(5).transpose() * B;  // can be done through dgemm

D = A * B * C;    // cannot be done in one func call through cblas
```

Note: comments are not Eigen transfer result. Instead, it is the ideal result. I'm not sure whether Eigen can transfer them.

There is also another question along with it: when will Eigen allocate temporary memory in those chain of operations? Are there any general rules that can help me figure out whether there is any allocation happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete chtz answer, all your hypothesis are true (provided you add the `.noalias()` decorator), and more generally any expression or subexpression that looks like a gemv/gemm will be turned to a single call, including transpose, blocks, conjugate, etc. You can look for examples in this [unit test](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/test/product_notemporary.cpp) counting the number of temporary, so `0` means a single blas-like call, `1` means that a temporary will be created before or after the blas-like call, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to avoid temporaries in your examples, you need to write

```
b.noalias() += w1 * A * a;
```

This is because Eigen cannot tell at compile time that `b`, `A`, and `a` do not alias, and therefore evaluates the product into a temporary.
[See here for details](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html#TopicAliasingMatrixMult).

Godbolt-demo: https://godbolt.org/g/VSfekp (Note that `-DEIGEN_USE_BLAS` is essentially equivalent to `-DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL`, but godbolt does not support MKL at the moment).

---

To your actual question: To determine whether an operation needs a temporary, you can compile with `-DEIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC` and surround sections which you think should not allocate by

```
Eigen::set_is_malloc_allowed(false); // mallocs after this cause assertions
// some code
Eigen::set_is_malloc_allowed(true); // mallocs are allowed again
```

This requires the result object to have the correct size before entering that section, of course.

Also, this will not help for fixed-sized expressions, since they will never allocate heap memory, but for fixed sized expressions using MKL is generally less efficient than Eigen (which depending on size, will fully unroll the necessary operations).